# Realization of network function and positive real function

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, synthesis

I just studied
'network realizibility theory' from 'Franklin F.kuo's ' book and it mainly talks about postive real functions from start to finish and to me what I understand that for a function to be realizable it should be a positive real function and as one of it's property suggest that poles and zeroes should be in Left half of plane .

But then how 'all pass filter' can be realized ? As it's zeroes are mirror image of poles about imaginary axis i.e if poles are in negative half then zeroes will be on right half of a plane and so it is not a positive real function then how does it's realization  possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The poles are the ones that must be in the left-half plane, which means the denominator must be a positive real function. Since the zeroes need to be reflected along the imaginary axis, then the polynomial at the numerator cannot be a positive real function, anymore. And this is completely fine, since the zeroes can be anywhere, they don't influence the stability. It's the realpart of the poles that affect the exponential term (transient).

Let's analyze two generic, allpass transfer functions, for a 1st and a 2nd order system:

$$\begin{align}
H_1(s)&=\frac{s-a}{s+b} \tag{1} \\
H_2(s)&=\frac{s^2-a_1s+a_0}{s^2+b_1s+b0} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Applying the inverse Laplace transform results in the impulse response. For the 1st order t.f. there is only one expression for the impulse reponse:

$$h_1(t)=-(a+b)\mathrm{e}^{-bt} \tag{3}$$

The presence of \$\mathrm{e}^{-bt}\$ shows that the function is of the form \$\mathrm{e}^{-x}\$ and thus will always be convergent. It's also dependent on the \$b\$ from the denominator, since \$-(a+b)\$ is just a constant.

For the 2nd order t.f., the impulse response will depend on whether \$b_1^2-4b_0\$ is greater than (overdamped), equal to (critically damped), or lesser than zero (underdamped). But all three will have one term in common: \$\mathrm{e}^{-b_1t}\$. Notice that it's identical to the 1st order t.f., except there is\$b_1\$ instead of \$b\$. Also notive its sign, and the fact that it's only a function of \$b_1\$, not any of the numerator terms.

Now, a 2nd order equation is very well defined in terms of it's roots \$r=\pm\alpha\pm j\beta\$ as:

$$s^2-2\Re(r)s+|r|^2=s^2-2\Re(r)s+\Re(r)^2+\Im(r)^2=0$$

This shows how, as long as the real part of the roots of the denominator are negative, the equation will result with a positive \$b_1\$ term, and \$\mathrm{e}^{-b_1t}\$ will always be convergent. Again, no term from the numerator.

Let's put the theory to practise. Here's a simple example in Octave of a 4th order allpass with random roots:

```
r=-randi(10,1,2)+1i*randi(10,1,2); r=[r;conj(r)](:), ...
num=poly(-r), ...
den=poly(r)
```

```
r =

  -9 + 3i
  -9 - 3i
  -3 + 2i
  -3 - 2i

num =

      1    -24    211   -774   1170

den =

      1     24    211    774   1170
```

The numerator is simply the poles with their real part positive. If what you say is true, then the system's step or impulse response should explode (i.e. should not be convergent):

[image: s=step, d=impulse]

Eppur si muove.

---

Since the question was not about building a SPICE example, I didn't think I should insist on that part, but, as per [jonk's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/514517/realization-of-network-function-and-positive-real-function/514543#comment1318581_514543), I'll extend this answer for future prying eyes.

In case the SPICE approach is obscure, there are three things that are at the base of it:

1. the voltage across a capacitor is \$v=\frac1C\int_t{i\,\mathrm{d}t}\$
2. in LTspice (since this is what I used), current sources are a lot more convergent-friendly than voltage sources
3. in LTspice, Laplace sources are very reliable in `.AC` (frequency-domain) analysis, but can be quite awful in `.TRAN` (time-domain)

With these in mind, a current source with a capacitor in parallel will act as an integrator for the voltage across it. It will also replace a \$\frac1s\$ Laplace expression. Using a VCCS will allow a voltage feedback, so now the first canonical form of a transfer function can be built:

[image: canon]

The difference between this and the first schematic is that in the latter, the nodes have summers, while the former shows a chain of integrators, which means they're multiplying. The reason for the SPICE version is simplification: why use summer *and* gain *and* integrator, when you can use one Swiss-army integrator? However, this means that the terms, as shown in the canonical form, if left untouched, will come out at the end of the chain all multiplied in the SPICE version. To circumvent that, take advantage of the fact that it is a chain, and so the last term can be divided by the previous one, then the previous one to the one before that, and so on. Now, when multiplied, they will simplfy on the way to the output leaving the terms clean. That's why, in the SPICE schematic, I left all the terms visible (i.e. I didn't just use the result of those divisions), so that even a value like `{24/1}` would make it clear that there are two terms in there, and how they got there.

Usually, long transfer functions are split into 2nd order sections. Here they would have resulted in \$s^2\pm 18s+90\$ and \$s^2\pm 6s+13\$, but I left it as a whole for better viewing of its terms.

As a last note, `G13` and `L1` (bottom right) form a differentiator, since \$v=L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}\$. The input is a step function, and `V(s)` gives just that. A step function, in Laplace domain, is \$\frac1s\$; this is multiplied with the transfer function. Differentiating this results in a clean transfer function, whose inverse Laplace is the impulse response. Thus, differentiating the step response gives the impulse response, `V(d)`.

Comment: I really enjoy it when you introduce readers to very general ways to use Spice simulation. You should write more when you do that, so that isn't closer to "just giving you a fish" but is instead closer to "teaching you how to fish for yourself." Anyway, +1 and thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answer! So functions that are not positive real (i.e system function of all pass filter) can also be realized then why almost in every book    realizibility  is related with postive real functions? , as if zeroes  has no importance in realizibility then there shouldn't be term like postive real function as  one of  it's necessary condition suggest that not only poles but zeroes must also lie in Left half of a plane.

Comment: @jonk You're right, it's not just the present company that would read this, so I tried to add something more. Thank you.

Comment: @user215805 I've updated my answer, maybe it's more clear now. If you think this answers your question, then please mark this down (the check mark) so that others, in the future, searching for similar answers, will find this question with a selected answer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen This has definitely become a bookmark for me until I've fully absorbed what you wrote. It's stuff I knew should be this easy to do, but hadn't sat down before to struggle over or to examine Mike's educational examples to see if it can be found there. So this will actually improve the breadth of my use of Spice tools. And for that, I'm in your debt. Thanks!

Comment: @jonk If it looks like I'm condescending, that is never my intent. If it does seem so, it's because I add details that are very basic, but only to people knowing what it's about. E.g. point 1) and the fact that it can replace a 1/s: now they're hardly any worth mentioning, but, believe it or not, for my part, it was only when someone told (showed) me the connection between the formula and the usage that I had a very loud click -- and this is the reason for the basic details, that someone might have missed the connection. Also, no debt, I'm here for the exchange of knowledge. You're welcome!

Comment: (you didn't imply or said I am condescending, but I always get this impression about my answers after I finish them). :-)